# Is removing fonts a bad idea (on Windows)?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7

Is removing fonts a bad idea (on Windows 7 / Server 2008 in particular)?

Comment: Why would you even want to do that?

Comment: From a usability perspective; using a font selection drop-down that's populated with more fonts than you need isn't helpful.  At a guess I'd only use around %5 (max) of the ones installed (by default) on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove a font used by the system, then everything will look dicky and weird.

Apart from that, you should be OK - but I can't think of any good reason to be removing fonts from servers, but if that's what you want to do, then go for it.

Comment: Thanks. I was mainly thinking of the impact on end-user machines but it occurred to me that there might be specific issues on servers.  Any idea how you'd identify fonts used by the system (or should I post that as a separate question)?

Comment: Unless the server needs those fonts for something that it does (PDF generation, perhaps) then it should not matter one bit.

Comment: @Adrian - there's no real definitive list. A quick-and-dirty method would be to go to the display settings, and customise your theme and just look at all the fonts in use for different things.